# How to stop Magento from sending emails via cron?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.1.0, queue

In Magento 1.9.1, order confirmation emails are queued and scheduled to be sent. How can I disable this? I would like Magento to send emails in real time like it used to do.

Comment: Is localhost able to send order mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard this involves a lot of customisation and changing of core files (of course via overwrite instead of really changing core files).

There is a solution via a extensions though. the SMTP Pro extension by Aschroder has the possibility to send emails directly without cron.

You can download it here
https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

Via this url you see the setting thats available. 
https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=percron

Comment: Awesome, the extension has achieved what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @KayIntVeen  I am using this extension, testing mail working good, but order mail not sending. How can I solve this issue?